# Javascript for loop not looping correctly

Tags: javascript, for-loop, increment

This is the Js Fiddler of the question because until it's run i don't see how this could possibly make sense. Loop of img src and i loop through them and place them in an img.src and load them and then append to an element. I have tried various other methods that just seems to not work and i have no idea why this would happen. Is it a problem with jsfiddler or is my code incorrect?

http://jsfiddle.net/shavyg2/GsQtn/embedded/result/

```
    /*Slide show*/
var container=$(".imageContainer");

var imageList=["http://blogs.adobe.com/captivate/files/2011/09/HTML5.jpg",               "http://www.hanselman.com/blog/content/binary/Windows-Live-Writer/HTML5-Support-for-Visual-Studio-2010---W_90C5/vshtml5_2.png",              "http://photos4.meetupstatic.com/photos/event/d/e/0/0/event_117656832.jpeg",               "http://e4dhtml5.azurewebsites.net/Content/html5man.jpg",               "http://la-matrice.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/css3.png"];

var count=0;
for(var i=0;i<imageList.length;i++){
    var image=new Image();
    var number=i+0;
    image.src=imageList[number];
    container.append(image);    
    container.append(imageList[number]);
    image.load();
    count++;
}

container.append(count);
```

Comment: the reason for the +0 is that i wanted to make sure it wasn't a reference of i being saved but the actual value of the expression. it didn't help either way. that was the same reason i did number as a new var as well. with or without it still didn't work;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove image.load() in your for loop.

```
for(var i=0;i<imageList.length;i++){
    var image=new Image();
    var number=i+0;
    image.src=imageList[number];
    container.append(image);    
    container.append(imageList[number]);
    count++;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6skav/

Get rid of "container.append(imageList[number]);" if you don't want the url to display.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/GsQtn/1/

This seems to do what you are intending. I think the problem is with all your extraneous `image` code. Basically the loop that I implemented looks like this:

```
for(var i=0;i<imageList.length;i++){
    var image = document.createElement("img");
    image.src=imageList[i];
    container.append(image);
    count++;
}
```

Comment: i figured it out. i didn't need to call load function like i do with audio and video tags

Answer (score 1):

I tried this in the fiddle and it worked.

```
for(var i=0;i<imageList.length;i++){
   var image=new Image();
   image.src=imageList[i];
  container.append(image);    
}
```

[image]

Comment: hmm maybe my screen was small.. let me check again

Comment: those are the pictures. it just doesn't work on my screen i have no idea why

Answer (score 0):

The reason this wasn't working was that I was calling the image.load() function. I got use to working with audio and video tags which recently i was doing, you don't need to call load for images.
In fact it doesn't have that method.

this is the final working code with out the testing stuff

```
  for(var i=0;i<imageList.length;i++){
    var image=new Image();
    image.src=imageList[i];
    container.append(image);    
    }
```